# Apt-get Issue Library Lock Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, updates, gnome-terminal, libraries

I just ran sudo apt-get autoremove to keep my boot disk clear. I always run sudo apt-get update afterward to make sure my disk is properly updated, otherwise I have difficulty booting up, even through recovery mode.

Just ran sudo apt-get update, after the autoremove command, and it returned the following:

```
Reading package lists...done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11:resource temporarily unavailable)
E:Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

That's it! What do I do to fix the command so I can run the update? I don't want to shut my computer off or even restart until I can fix this. I also hope this isn't a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Weird. I just ran sudo apt-get autoremove again, to see if it would fix the problem. It did. I ran sudo-apt-get update afterward, and it worked perfectly fine. 

But it didn't ask for my password like it normally does. Should that worry me? Could this be a sign of something not functioning quite right?

Comment: Haha, that's nothing to worry, sudo caches your passwords for a small fixed amount of time, intended as a convenience so that you need not re-enter the password time and again. Look at the [sudo manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html)

Comment: Fabulous, I've been trying to find out where to go to learn more about how to control this OS. I love it, but it's my first time running linux. I'll be sure to look through that manual. Maybe I should do a few experiments too? Run a few of them?

Comment: Learning is experimenting. Go on! And GNU/Linux surely has an active community, here and elsewhere, and also lots of documentation, offline and online, to support you if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Run sudo apt-get autoremove one more time before trying to update. This fixed the problem for me. Very simple.

Comment: The likely reason that the problem was fixed is that something else (probably not `autoremove`) was doing Apt-related things and you waited long enough for it to finish, and it released the lock when it finished.

Comment: Huh, how strange. It didn't tell me any of that. I wonder why?